# How to read specific lines with bufferedReader

Tags: java

I need to find some specific data from txt file, see code bellow.

```
while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null) {
    //pokial obsahuje string zapíš do array
    if (line.toLowerCase().contains("list c.")) {
        parsedData.add(line);
    }
    if(line.toLowerCase().startsWith("re")) {
        parsedData.add(line);//add found data to array
        //i need to access and save second and third line after this one
    }

    System.out.println(line);
}
```

In the  second condition, when I find a line that starts with "re" I need to save the second and third line after this specific one.

Comment: What did you try to achieve that and why did it not work?

Comment: i tried bufferedReader.readLine(); and after i added line to array but it just duplicated data, it read same line twice i believe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from your question i am not sure but if your target is to get next couple of lines (for example 2) after receiving re at start of line, you can do it by having some flags.

```
 boolean needsToConsider = false;
        int countOfLines = 2; 
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null) {

            if(needsToConsider && countOfLines > 0){
                // add here
                countOfLines--;
                if(countOfLines == 0)
                    needsToConsider = false;
            }
            //pokial obsahuje string zapíš do array
            if (line.toLowerCase().contains("list c.")) {
                parsedData.add(line);
            }
            if(line.toLowerCase().startsWith("re")) {
                parsedData.add(line);//add found data to array
                //i need to access and save second and third line after this one
                needsToConsider = true;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach here might be to just use a counter to keep track of hitting those second and third lines:

```
int counter = 0;

while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null) {
    if (line.toLowerCase().contains("list c.")) {
        parsedData.add(line);
    }
    else if (line.toLowerCase().startsWith("re")) {
        parsedData.add(line);
        counter = 2;
    }
    else if (counter > 0) {
        // add second and third lines after "re" here
        parsedData.add(line);
        --counter;
    }
}
```

A more advanced approach could be to read in the entire portion of text of interest, and then use a regex matcher to extract what you want.